# Href: Target ID in Current DIV

Tags: javascript, html, html-lists

I have a list of `<li>` items being generated from a CMS/DB. Each `<li>` has a `<div>` in it which contains a link to a lightbox (a hidden `<div>`). The link targets the id of the hidden `<div>` (#inline-content-print) so the javascript plugin triggers and pulls up the lightbox.

The problem I'm running into is that all of the `<li>`s on the page generate with the same hidden `div` id (I can change this to classes). So no matter which `<li>` href is clicked, it always pulls up the lightbox for the first `<li>` on the page (the first instance of the id). I need a way for the href to say "open #inline-content-print" from THIS `div` (the one the link being clicked lives in)".

```
<li>
<div class="store-buttons-bg hide-print-buttons-{tag_Hide-Print-Buttons}">

<a href="#inline-content-print" class="various store-button">PRINT</a>

        <div style="display: none;" id="inline-content-print">
        CONTENT OF LIGHTBOX
        </div>
        <!-- end inline-content-print -->

</div>
</li>
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What plugin are you using? If you're able to change the structure, it's best to do so

Answer (score 0):

What server side language are you using? Is it producing these list items in a loop? Is there an index on that loop? If so, this would work for you.

```
[Server language version of a for loop with an index variable named "i"]
<li>
<div class="store-buttons-bg hide-print-buttons-{tag_Hide-Print-Buttons}">

<a href="#inline-content-print_[server language output of "i"]" class="various store-button">PRINT</a>

        <div style="display: none;" id="inline-content-print_[server language output of "i"]">
        CONTENT OF LIGHTBOX
        </div>
        <!-- end inline-content-print -->

</div>
</li>
[server language version of an end to the for loop]
```

Comment: Thanks. It's built using Adobe's Business Catalyst, which (I believe) is built upon ASP.Net, but I have no access to any server-side goodies.  My suspicion is that I need some Javascript which, essentially, states that the hrefs clicked need to target a class (or ID) which lives in the same <li>.

Comment: I figured out a way around it using the platform (Business Catalyst). Looking at invertedSpear's comment where he appended language to #inline-content-print_ gave me the idea to append a unique identifier (product code) in the same place. My client needs to enter in the product code when creating the individual products in the CMS.  So I have a working solution, but it doesn't answer how this would be done with javascript in a normal situation.

Comment: @user1669207: Glad it spurred you in the right direction. The answer you seek is going to depend on what js library you are using, and which lightbox plug-in. Since you never answered BoltClocks question asked in the comment to your original question, there isn't a way for us to answer that for you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to do this with jQuery/Javascript, you could use something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('li a.store-button').click(function(e)
    {
        var lightboxElement = $(e.currentTarget).find('div');
        lightboxElement.show(); // or whatever function you need to display
        return false;
    });
});
```

Which is a little script that:

1. Waits for the page to load.
2. Finds your list elements (by `li` object type and the class on the links)
3. Intercepts click events.
4. Finds the `div` element nested in the link that was clicked.
5. Displays (or runs another function) on the target lightbox element.